# Issue with Git folder placement and Heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

When I first ran my rails generator it created a folder inside of the folder I wanted to have my repository work from. What I mean by this is my github folder structure looks like this:

https://github.com/milosbunijevac/medRails

the medtools folder has the entire project, but the initial repository was started one level above the medtools folder as the repository above shows.

When I run the following commands:

```
heroku create 
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 heroku/ruby
```

and then git push heroku master from the root directory (one level above medtools) I get an error saying that app not compatible with buildpack and that the push was rejected. I'm thinking it has something to do with this strange folder structure. Do you guys and gals have any insights as to how I might fix this issue and get my project to deploy to heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could locally move everything one level up, and push back to GitHub, done in a bash session:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git mv medtools/* .
git rm medtools
git add .
git commit -m "move medtools content"
git push
```

As the [OP Milos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7066742/milos) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903519/issue-with-git-folder-placement-and-heroku-deployment/45905152?noredirect=1#comment78777137_45905152), you might have to tweak the `.gitignore` content.

Comment: On that second step, do i go into the medtools folder and type in git mv medtools/*, or do i go to the directory above it and type in git mv medtools/*?

Comment: @Milos above: the goal is to move the folder content.

Comment: when i type in git mv medtools/* . it just tells me the source directory is empty, source=medtools/node_modules, destination=node_modules

Comment: @Milos yet, https://github.com/milosbunijevac/medRails/tree/master/medtools is not empty. Try and clone your repo again, before doing the `git mv medtools/* .`.

Comment: The reason it wasn't working was because there was a .gitignore inside the medtools directory. Once I removed all the entries from that, recommited, did the git mv medtools/* . thing, and then it all transferred. I then readded the gitignore information back into the file and committed. Everything works great now.

Comment: @Milos Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.